# whats the difference between fillable and guard in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am newbie in Laravel and want to understand this with example.
what are main difference between fillable and guard in laravel? 
How those are differentiated?
Please share one basic example.

Comment: Better to search in Laravel documentation. You will get answer of your question. Anyway you can check the difference at there.
[http://hndr.me/blog/laravel-mass-assignment-protection-blacklist-vs-whitelist/]     Hope this will help you.

Comment: please go through the [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) under the Mass Assignment heading.

Answer (score 43):

Example 1

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];
```

It means we want to insert only name,and email colmn values

Example 2

```
protected $guarded = ['name', 'email'];
```

It means we want to ignore only name & email we don't want to insert values of name & email colmn

Example 3

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

We want to insert all columns values

Answer (score 8):

First as a newbie refer the documentation on laravel site. I suppose you are asking about fillable vs guarded.

Fillable is ready for mass assignments i.e. you can use fill() with array of value sets instead of one-one assignments. Below name and email are fillable.

```
 class User extends Eloquent{
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];
}  

....
    $user = User::create($request->all);
```

Guarded is just opposite of fillable.

keep in mind there is one more "hidden" which means its not available for json parsing. so if you use

```
 return User::all();
```

the returned json will skip all fields mentioned in hidden. Also the hidden doesn't explicitly means guarded.

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel, `$fillable` attribute is used to specify those fields which are to be mass assignable. `$guarded` attribute is used to specify those fields which are to be made non mass assignable.

`$fillable` serves as a "white list" of attributes that should be mass assignable and `$guarded` acts just the opposite of it as a "black list" of attributes that should not be mass assignable.

If we want to block all the fields from being mass-assigned, we can use:

`protected $guarded = ['*'];`

If we want to make all the fields mass assignable, we can use:

`protected $guarded = [];`

If we want to make a particular field mass assignable, we can use:

`protected $fillable = ['fieldName'];`

Lastly, if we want to block a particular field from being mass assignable, we can use:

`protected $guarded = ['fieldName'];`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this question and after research I came to this conclusion

Using fillable is good when you have 2–10 fields, but what if you have 20–50 fields in your model? I have experienced creating a table with 56 fields to be exact, and just 3 out of those fields are needed to be protected. Trust me, it’s quite of a work. “I’m not saying that it’s not good” using fillable in this situation, you may, but if you want an easier way to secure it from mass-assignment, then guarded will be more preferable.

Comment: Are you thinking that or did you just copy [this article](https://codewithtravel.medium.com/laravel-mass-assignment-guarded-or-fillable-7c3a64b49ca6)?